# How can I resolve the error: Couldn’t modify partition map because file system verification failed

Tags: partitioning, boot-camp

I deleted my Bootcamp partition from Disk Utility by accident. I'm trying to create it back but this message appears:

```
Partition failed with the error:
Couldn’t modify partition map because file system verification failed.
```

Comment: Try the "Repair" button on the disk first?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you delete the partition, there is no way to effectively recover that partition table.  Thus it is gone.  YOUR DATA is still there, but you'll need to use some form of recovery tool to be able to recover that information.

DO NOT create another bootcamp partition until you recover the data that you want from the corrupt partition.

[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a very good tool to help you restore that partition without losing any data. Here is a [tutorial](http://tjwallas.weebly.com/5/post/2011/03/how-to-fix-or-rebuild-the-mbr-and-recover-lost-partitions-on-a-hard-disk.html) on how to use it (You can skip the ubuntu live CD part).